# Basis for the set of functions $f$ that vanish for $n \geq N_f \in \Bbb{N}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modules, abelian-groups

The set of all functions $f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n \geq N_f$ for some $N_f \in \Bbb{N}$ dependent upon $f$, forms a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.

*Proof*.  Let $M$ be the set of all such functions.  Then clearly, $0 \in M$.  Suppose that $f, g \in M$

$$
(f-g)(n) = 0, \ \forall \ n \geq \text{max}(N_f, N_g)
$$

Done since scalar multiplication clearly holds, and we've shown closure of a subset $M \subset \Bbb{Z}$-module $\{ \text{functions } h : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}\}$ under subtraction.

What is a basis for $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ the function that assigns to each $k$ the value

$f(k):= \delta_{kn}$

Then $\{f_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a base for your $\mathbb{Z}-$module $M$.

In fact if you consider $f\in M$, then

$f=\sum_{k}^{N_f}f(k)f_k$

Comment: I saw that just as you posted.   Was wondering if there are other bases as well that seem just as natural, such as the mesa function that vanishes past a certain point (all 1's and then remaining values are 0's).

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond i have not in mind another base that is natural, sorry